# How to test an actor?

Tags: ponylang

How can I test an actor? Since the calls are not synchronous, and one messages can cause multiple messages to be sent, what are the ways of testing it?

E.g. How can I test that my actor sent 3 messages in response to another message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general you cannot test what an actor has done unless it interacts with a trait or interface you provide in the construction or in an input message. So if you have an actor like the following.

```
actor MyActor
  be do_stuff(receiver: MyReceiver)
```

You use a pattern where you combine a timer, for a timeout, and a wrapper actor that provides `MyReceiver` to test if the actor actually did send the message or sequence of messages that where expected.

Pony already includes the `ponytest` package with some support for this kind of tests. You can check the [PonyTest actor](https://github.com/CausalityLtd/ponyc/blob/master/packages/ponytest/ponytest.pony) at GitHub. Basically you have to specify a timeout and ensure one of your actors calls `complete` in the test helper for success. Note that the API has changed since the last stable version.